# Combine objects in an array of objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

i am having trouble combining objects from an array of Objects in typescript.

the Array looks like that:

```
0: {type: 'FeatureCollection', features: Array(134)}
1: {type: 'FeatureCollection', features: Array(109)}
```

what i need is an object (no array) with all "features" combined  - so that it looks like this:

```
{type: 'FeatureCollection', features: Array(243)}
```

i am very new to typescript so sorry for that probably easy question...

Thank you so much!!

EDIT: maybe the question was not too good to understand. Hope this helps: Array(134) means there are 134 Objects inside. this does what i need manually when the array of objects (collection) is 2 long:

```
  const result = [...collection[0].features, ...collection[1].features];
  const resultCollection: FeatureCollection = collection[0];
  resultCollection.features = result;
```

i need to make this work for any length of collection.

Comment: What does `Array(134)` mean? Is that meant to be a `number[]` array containing a single-element value of `134`? Or do you mean an array (`unknown[]` or `any[]`) that contains 134 elements?

Comment: Just those 2 elements? What about other values for `type:` besides `'FeatureCollection'`?

Comment: Array(134) means there are 134 Objects inside. this does what i need manually when the array of objects (collection) is 2 long: 


```const result = [...collection[0].features, ...collection[1].features];
  const resultCollection: FeatureCollection = collection[0];
  resultCollection.features = result;```


i need to make this work for any length of collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? You'll need to add types, but you can merge the `features` arrays from all entries in the `data` array using vanilla JS methods.

1. Create the `output` object and specify its `type`.
2. Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select the entries in `data` with the matching type.
3. Use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to select the `features` array from each of the entries above and project their contents into a single array.

```js
const data = [
  { type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [1, 2, 3] },
  { type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [4, 5, 6] }
];

const output = { 
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: data
    .filter(obj => obj.type === 'FeatureCollection')
    .flatMap(obj => obj.features) 
};
  
console.dir(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the reduce function :

```js
const array = [
  {type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [1, 2, 3]},
  {type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [4, 5, 6]},
  {type: 'Test', features: [4, 5, 6]}
]

const merged = array.reduce((array, item) => {
  const found = array.find((i) => i.type === item.type);
  if (found) {
    found.features.push(...item.features);
  } else {
    array.push(item);
  }
  return array;
}, []);

console.log(merged);
```

---- EDITED ----

option 2 :

```js
const array = [
  {type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [1, 2, 3]},
  {type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [4, 5, 6]},
  {type: 'Test', features: [4, 5, 6]}
]

const merged = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
  if (obj[item.type]) {
    obj[item.type].push(...item.features);
  } else {
    obj[item.type] = item.features;
  }
  return obj;
}, {} as {[key: string]: number[]});

const keys = Object.keys(merged);
const result = keys.map((k) => ({type: k, features: merged[k]}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Using `array.find()` inside your reducer is going to give you awful runtime complexity `O( n^2 )`  - you should generate an initial grouping of `array` by `type` in a `Map`, then you can get runtime down to `O( n )`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but im am having trouble getting the Types right. in this line
```(obj[item.type])```
i get this error: 
```(parameter) obj: FeatureCollection<Geometry | GeometryCollection, Properties>
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"FeatureCollection"' can't be used to index type 'FeatureCollection<Geometry | GeometryCollection, Properties>'.
  Property 'FeatureCollection' does not exist on type 'FeatureCollection<Geometry | GeometryCollection, Properties>'.ts(7053)```
any hint how to fix that?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you using that library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.data.featurecollection?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest 

If it's the case all objects have attribute 'type' with value 'FeatureCollection', you just have to create a FeatureCollection object then append all features to our new object.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `Array.prototype.reduce` function and the spread operator

```js
const original = [
  { type: "banana", features: ["34", "wow", "hotdog"] },
  { type: "banana", features: ["dog", "cat", "recursion"] },
];

const compress = (original) => original.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc.features = [...(acc.features ?? []), ...cur.features];
  return acc;
}, { type: (original[0].type) });

console.log(compress(original));
```